# java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

New to JDBC and trying to connect to data base in MySql workbench. Following is the Java code

```
import java.sql.*;


public class Demo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {   
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//students?useSSL=false"; 
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";
        String query = "Select * from students";
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);  
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rt = st.executeQuery(query);
        
        rt.next();
        String name = rt.getString("stu_name");
        
        System.out.println(name);
        
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }

}
```

Following is the error being thrown:

> Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.

My MySQL workbench version is 8.0.21 with same version for mysql-connector/J
[image: Database in workbench]

Comment: `Malformed database URL`. Remove the second double slash and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the problem is the double slash (//) in your URL. Try

```
 String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students?useSSL=false";
```

instead.

Comment: ya, just figured that out ,
thanks for your help 